# SQLite: select all rows made in a specific month

Tags: sqlite, date, time

i want to get all entries from a SQLite table, which have the timestamp from the same month.

For example, the user can type in "July" and then i want to get all entries made in the 7. month.

The current "time"-column is a simple string and in the Format (DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS)

Is there a way to do this with SQLite or will i need to use code in my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your time strings have a fixed length, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE time LIKE '__.07%';
```

However, you should always stored dates in one of the [supported date/time formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) so that you are able to use the built-int date/time functions.